# Excel Calculate the date difference from today from a cell of "7/6/2012 10:26:42"

Tags: excel, date

So I have a cell with `7/6/2012  10:26:42` inputted, I want to show the date difference from today in another cell.

I tried to extract `7/6/2012` with `=LEFT(A1, Find(" ", A1, 1) -1)` but turned out theres a value error.

The formula works when I make A1 `'7/6/2012  10:26:42`, however it is not ideal because I have to work with the whole column.

Answer (score 32):

You can use the datedif function to find out difference in days.

```
=DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"d")
```

**Quote from excel.datedif.com**

The mysterious datedif function in Microsoft Excel

The Datedif function is used to calculate interval between two dates in days, months or years.

This function is available in all versions of Excel but is not documented. It is not even listed in the "Insert Function" dialog box.
Hence it must be typed manually in the formula box.
Syntax

`DATEDIF( start_date, end_date, interval_unit )`

start_date  from date
end_date    to date (must be after start_date)
interval_unit   Unit to be used for output interval
Values for interval_unit

interval_unit    Description

D   Number of days

M   Number of complete months

Y   Number of complete years

YD  Number of days excluding years

MD  Number of days excluding months and years

YM  Number of months excluding years

### Errors

Error   Description

#NUM!   The end_date is later than (greater than) the start_date
or interval_unit has an invalid value.
#VALUE! end_date or start_date is invalid.

Comment: broken link to excel.datedif.com

Answer (score 4):

If that's a valid date/time entry then excel simply stores it as a number (days are integers and the time is the decimal part) so you can do a simple subtraction.

I'm not sure if 7/6 is 7th June or 6th July, assuming the latter then it's a future date so you can get the difference in days with

`=INT(A1-TODAY())`

Make sure you format result cell as general or number (not date)

Answer (score 2):

For the difference between A1 and Today's date you could enter: 
     =ABS(TODAY()-A1)

which returns the (fractional) number of days between the dates.

You're likely getting a #VALUE! error in your formula because Excel treats dates as numbers.

Answer (score 2):

```
DAYS(start_date,end_date):
```

For example:

```
DAYS(A1,TODAY())
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just make it easy and simple.  If I need to know the number of days between today and say, March 10th, 2015, I can just enter the simple formula.

Lets say the static date is March 10th, 2015, and is in cell O5.

The formula to determine the number of days between today and O5 would be, =O5-Today()

Nothing fancy or DATEDIF stuff.  Obviously, the cell where you type this formula in must have a data type of 'number'.  Just type your date in normally in the reference cell, in this case O5.

Answer (score 0):

`=ROUND((TODAY()-A1)/365,0)` will provide number of years between date in cell A1 and today's date

Comment: That last formula was exactly what I was looking for but removed the last '0' and replaced with '12' to show years and `months =ROUND((TODAY()-A1)/365,12)`, thanks!

Comment: To get only years without decimal value converted above to int =INT(ROUND((TODAY()-A1)/365,12)).

Answer (score 0):

*In all instances the # refers to the cell number

You really don't need the datedif functions; for example:

I'm working on a spreadsheet that tracks benefit eligibility for employees.

I have their hire dates in the "A" column and in column B is =(TODAY()-A#)

And you just format the cell to display a general number instead of date.

It also works very easily the other way: I also converted that number into showing when the actual date is that they get their benefits instead of how many days are left, and that is simply

=(90-B#)+TODAY()

Just make sure you're formatting cells as general numbers or dates accordingly.

Hope this helps.